# how to use data set to compute the place holders arithmetically

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to compare the x value with the place holder

please help me with your inputs

x is a number like 1500 or 2100 or whatever.

function would be a stored evaluation like x > 1400 and x < 1600

when i am using relations i am getting errors

```
   var diff = (lastScannedDate - DateTime.UtcNow).Days;
   var deviceStatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(_paasConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration("DeviceStatus").ToString());

   foreach (var key in deviceStatus.Keys)
   {
       foreach (var value in deviceStatus.Values)
       {
           function = relation[0].Replace("and","&&").Replace("x",x);

           DataTable f_dt = new DataTable();
           var f_var = f_dt.Compute(function,"");

           if (bool.Parse(f_var.ToString()) { do stuff  }
       }
   }
```

Comment: here is my sql code  IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Configuration
  WHERE [Key] = 'DeviceStatus'
  )
BEGIN
 INSERT [dbo].[Configuration] (
  [CreatedOn]
  ,[CreatedBy]
  ,[Key]
  ,[Value]
  )
 VALUES (
  CAST(N'2017-01-19 05:38:05.997' AS DATETIME)
  ,1
  ,N'DeviceStatus'
  ,N'{"{0}<=2":"ONLINE","{0}>5":"OFFLINE"}'
  )
END   i need to compare the place holders with values

Comment: here is my sql code

Comment: your question cannot be perceived...
your code snippet is fragmented - why do you organize 2 cycles if you don't use 'key' and 'value'? what is 'relation[0]'?